# unwanted space being generated before nav bar

Tags: html

Trying to figure out whats causing this space at the top before the nav bar. [www.omegadesignla.com](http://www.omegadesignla.com) There is a random nbsp; nbsp; space charater being generated into the html when you insepect the element, and I can't figure out whats causing it. Here is the beginning html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Omega Design | LA</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Web development and printing services serving the greater los angeles area">
      <meta name="keywords" content="web development, printing, graphics design, los angeles, santa clarita">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
          <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
              <span><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logofinal.png"></a><span>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
              <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Contact us</a></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                  <a href="#">Services</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="services.html#printing">Print Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Web Development</a></li>
                   <!--  <li><a href="services.html">Promotional Items</a></li> -->
                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li> -->
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </nav>    
  <div class="container">
    <header>

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-6 small-centered columns"> <!-- large centered -->
        <a id="topbutton" href="#" class="button large radius button">Take the tour!</a>

        </div>



      </header>
```

Comment: Validator thinks there’s something wrong with your head (element, not yours), seems related to the meta elements: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.omegadesignla.com/  (Quite a lot of other errors as well …)

Comment: hmm so which is it? I don't understand the error.

Comment: Random idea, but try ending the tag with a `/>`. The charset and viewport are ended this way, but the others aren't.

Comment: thanks i tried this but it didnt do anything